# Why JSDoc duplicates JSON records if I put ES6 "export" in front of an identifier?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Given following source code:

```
/** Comment */
const foo = {};
```

Generating JSON JSDoc documentation for it:

```
npx jsdoc -X foo.js
```

produces expected result:

```
[{
  "description": "Comment",
  "name": "foo",
  "kind": "constant",
  "scope": "global"
}]
```

But if i place `export` ES6 keyword in front of the identifier:

```
/** Comment */
export const foo = {};
```

the resulting JSON will contain two records for "foo"! One as previous and one "undocumented". Any hints why such strange behavior? Any way to fix it?

```
[{
  "description": "Comment",
  "name": "foo",
  "kind": "constant",
  "scope": "global"
},
{
  "undocumented": true,
  "name": "foo",
  "kind": "constant",
  "scope": "global"
}]
```

Comment: What about: `const foo = {};` Put your comments above that and then export it like `export foo;`?

Comment: There is no such syntax in ES2018, the closest I can think about is `export {foo};` which does not help, same "undocumented" item out of nowhere :(

Answer (score 1):

According to the [JSDoc documentation](http://usejsdoc.org/howto-es2015-modules.html#exported-values), **you need to include a `@module` tag** when using module exports.

You could do:

```
/** @module some/module */

/** Comment */
const foo = {};
```

or simply

```
/** @module */

/** Comment */
const foo = {};
```

Comment: That was my first idea. Unfortunately, adding @module does not remove the "undocumented" item :(

Comment: Thanks! Helped to me: https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1716